# How to use Cocoapods in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm a beginner, just getting started with coding in Swift 5 and Xcode. I'm trying to develop a basic iOS app and want to use a cocoapod to my project.

I've managed to successfully install the cocoapod to Xcode and I can see it in Xcode. However, I can't seem to figure out where to add the relevant codes and use it.

For example, can somebody please help me make use of the following Cocoapod; "Gallery'

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Gallery

Many Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about what you've tried already?

Comment: If you've installed the Gallery pod, then in your code you `import Gallery` and away you go. Detailed instructions are here: https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery, including example code at https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery/blob/master/Example/GalleryDemo/GalleryDemo/Sources/ViewController.swift What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what step you're on, but in general you add a Cocoapod with the following steps:

- Add the pod to your Podfile:

```
pod `Gallery`
```

- Run `pod install` in your project directory.
- Open the generated `.xcworkspace` file.
- Import the library when you need it in a file:

```
import Gallery
```